# Caching a large number of images in a jQuery/HTML5 application

Tags: jquery, caching, html, storage, manifest

I am building a web application in jQuery/HTML5 which will run in Webkit-based browsers on touchscreen kiosks.

There are a large (thousands) number of images which the application uses, which I need cached to each browser.

At first I thought a HTML5 cache manifest would be the best option (with the thousands of image URLs listed), but now I wonder if there is a better way? I would consider extensions/plugins too...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UPDATE: We have decided to take advantage of the browser's cache which can do almost everything we need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I like this plugin:  http://alexrabarts.github.com/jquery-cacheimage/

Here's another alternative:  http://technosophos.com/content/precaching-images-jquery-slightly-better-way

And if you wanted to do preloading:  http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript

EDIT:  If offline browsing is needed, application cache is the way to go with HTML cache manifest.  Here are some resources:

http://softwareas.com/offline-apps-with-application-cache-quickstart-tips-and-deep-dive

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1944-Experimenting-With-HTML5-s-Cache-Manifest-For-Offline-Web-Applications.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need the images to be cached permanently in each browser, even after the browser restarts. There is likely to be thousands of images totalling hundreds of megabytes of data.

I might have to store the images as base-64 strings in the browser's local storage.

Comment: @Anarchitect:

I think you're going to have to use application cache for HTML5.  I don't think there is a faster/efficient way, especially since that method would be native.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Thousands of images, potentially hundreds of MB's
This would be out of localstorage's approx 5 MB Cap. You could do a ClientDatabase and request some massive amount of space.

## Resources I've dug up

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/
http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/
http://creativepark.net/blog/entry/id/1191
http://ajaxian.com/archives/view-source-tutorial-sticky-notes-with-html5-and-css3

Comment: Thanks for this, I am doing some experiments with Web DB now. Documentation has been a bit patchy though, so any pointers would be appreciated!