# Combining HTML5 localStorage and local Database for more space?

Tags: html, caching, local-storage, offline, local-database

I am developing a web application for remote areas with little internet connectivity and was wondering if I can use HTML5 localStorage with a maximum size of 10MB and HTML5 local Database with a maximum size of 10MB for a total of 20MB of offline storage (Not including HTML5 Application Cache) or do browsers combine these quotas? Is HTML5 Application Cache a separate quota? Are there any other ways of getting more than 10MB of persistent storage?

Comment: See these related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568557/caching-a-large-number-of-images-in-a-jquery-html5-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914143/html5-local-storage-and-sqlite-storage-limits

Comment: I previously looked at both of these topics and while one asks the question is the quota shared, that part of the question was never answered. My question is simply are the quotas for offline storage shared or separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You might expect the browser to
>   enforce a single limit for all storage
>   an origin can use, but the major
>   browsers are actually enforcing limits
>   separately for each storage mechanism.

Source: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/#quotas

That answers your question I think.